# How to handle Servlet in login form?

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, authentication, console

I'm building a web application using only JSP pages and Servlets.
I'm trying to make a login form, but I can't access to home page. 
Does anyone know how to handle this?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

try {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Iterator it = list_etudiant().iterator();
    System.out.println("username" + username);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Etudiant et = (Etudiant) it.next();
        String user_name = et.getEmailEtudiant();
        String pass_word = et.getPasswordEtudiant();
        if ((user_name == null ? username == null : user_name.equals(username)) && (pass_word == null ? password == null : pass_word.equals(password))) {

            response.sendRedirect("View/Home.jsp");
        }

    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
}

}
```

And another question, why I can't see the output in Netbeans console? For example when I want to print something:

```
System.out.println("username is : "+username);
```

I can't find the output and I just get this:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((user_name == null ? username == null : user_name.equals(username)) && 
            (pass_word == null ? password == null : pass_word.equals(password))) {

        response.sendRedirect("View/Home.jsp");
    }
```

I hope your  rest of code work fine.
Refer to above code snippet. I guess your perspective is username & password should not be null & need to be equal.

```
        if (((user_name != null) && (user_name.equals(username)))
            && ((pass_word != null) && (pass_word.equals(password)))) {
        System.out.println("username is : " + username);  // If you need to print it on console
        response.sendRedirect("View/Home.jsp");
    }
```

Your conditional checking is incorrect. Please refer [?: Operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html)